# Timeout::Error with Selenium/Capybara/Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, timeout, cucumber, capybara

I have a Scenario step

```
When I fill in the following:
  | Credit Card Number | 4111111111111111 |
  | CCV Value          | 123              |
  | First name         | First            |
  | Last name          | Last             |
  | Address            | 123 My St.       |
  | City               | My City          |
```

This step is inconsistently failing with a Timeout::Error

```
(::) failed steps (::)

execution expired (Timeout::Error)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2020:in `read_status_line'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2009:in `read_new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1050:in `request_without_fakeweb'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1037:in `request_without_fakeweb'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request_without_fakeweb'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:41
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:40:in `/^(?:|I )fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
```

And its even weirder that the step fails when filling different fields. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was with Fakeweb gem.. i removed that gem and now it seems to be working..